# GraphQl federation server that supports subscriptions

Tags: graphql, graphql-subscriptions

I'm currently evaluating different GraphQl servers in order to find one that supports **subscriptions on a federated schema**.

Apollo and HotChocolate don't support that. HotChocolate is going to (its on the roadmap) but I can't wait; and Apollo wants me to run a seperate subscription service which I'd like to avoid.

Anybody know of a service that allows me to use subscriptions this way, now?
To be clear: I only need the federation server that supports subscriptions. The single schemas behind may still be served thru hot chocolate.

Answer (score 1):

Federated Subscriptions are now supported in GraphOS!

https://www.apollographql.com/blog/announcement/backend/federated-subscriptions-in-graphos-real-time-data-at-scale/

Answer (score 0):

https://tyk.io/docs/getting-started/key-concepts/graphql-subscriptions/#how-we-are-ahead-of-everyone-else

After some digging, I found this. Looks very promising. They claim to support subscriptions on federation.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried https://github.com/sammysaglam/federation-with-subscriptions?

**disclaimer**: i am the author of this library.

it uses apollo server express under the hood, and supports federation with subscriptions. it works using schema stitching by converting federation SDL into schema-stitching SDL, allowing full gateway to microservice subscriptions support.

Comment: Were using HotChocolate for now, theyve added the support. If we run into problems, i will check out your library :) thanks!